# Calculated metric from same event category/action/label

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a dashboard in Google data studio and I'm trying to add a click through rate for a widget I am using, which has been already tagged as **click** and **impression** under event label.(under the same event category and event action)

I could not figure out how to get the unique events as a result instead of a boolean for regex filter. As a workaround, I have tried:

```
Count(Regex_match(event label, 'click')) / count(regex match(event label, 'impession'))
```

But got a null result as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the current error is down to the misspelling of 'impression' but REGEXP_MATCH brings back true or false so counting will count all of the event labels on both sides.

I think you need to do a sum of a case statement to achieve what you need.

Try creating two metrics as follows and then doing the division as a third metric.

```
SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(event label, 'click') then 1 else 0 end)

SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(event label, 'impression') then 1 else 0 end)
```